# converting array to string in javascript while controlling precision of floats

Tags: javascript, formatting, tostring, number-formatting

I have a javascript array-of-number-triples, of the form

```
[[123.55555,4.44444444,0.123455666],[12344.44444,7.77777777,8.8888101010],...,[1.000102340240,123.02020400,1.121212121212]]
```

This converts nicely to a string with the 'toString()' method. (Edit: Actually, the two-dimensional nature of the array is lost by 'toString()', but it doesn't bother me because each line has 3 numbers, so that structure is still implicit in the string.)

However, what if I want to truncate/round (I don't really care which) the numbers at 2 or 3 decimal places? It seems like 'toFixed()' doesn't work for arrays...

Nb: I'm aware that I could loop through the array and truncate each number manually and piece together the resulting strings, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant way...

Comment: You will need to loop in some way and modify the items in the array. If you don't want to imperatively loop, then you can use a array method such as map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thanks... too bad I got all this heat for asking something I didn't see answered elsewhere and whose answer taught me something... [hum...](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented; you can use map:

```js
console.log(
  [[123.55555,4.44444444,0.123455666],[12344.44444,7.77777777,8.8888101010],[1.000102340240,123.02020400,1.121212121212]]
  .map(numbers=>numbers.map(number=>number.toFixed(3)))
  .toString()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array=[[123.55555,4.44444444,0.123455666],[12344.44444,7.77777777,8.8888101010]];
array=array.map(function(item){
  return item.map(function(num){
    return parseFloat(num.toFixed(2));
  });
});
console.log(array.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const array = [[123.55555, 4.44444444, 0.123455666], [12344.44444, 7.77777777, 8.8888101010]];
const result = [].concat.apply([], array).map(n => n.toFixed(2)).toString();

console.log(result);
```